# How to delete a particular message from openfire using PHP

Tags: php, openfire

I am working on chat application in which my requirement is to delete
a chat message from chatroom after 24hours. So that if any user will login from the app after 24hours they cannot be able to read that message because that message has been expired. So for this functionality I have used this approach first that this message is stored in ofMessageArchive table of openfire so I have deleted the message manually from this table but after this also if any user login from the application they will be able to see that message again.

I have also tested this for multiple users.

I have also refer the following link but it is not working. Please help me
https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-2199

Answer (score 0):

There is a XEP that discuss about this: XEP-0079.

The point is insert an ['expire-at'](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0079.html#conditions-def-expireat) condition inside the message, like this example:

```
<message
    from='northumberland@shakespeare.lit'
    id='richard2-4.1.247'
    to='kingrichard@royalty.england.lit'>
  <body>My lord, dispatch; read o'er these articles.</body>
  <amp xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/amp'>
    <rule condition='expire-at'
          action='drop'
          value='2004-01-01T00:00:00Z'/>
  </amp>
</message>
```

But, there are some open issues about this XEP in the [Openfire backlog.](https://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/XIFF-87?jql=text%20~%20%22XEP-0079%22)

So, this feature is not ready yet, I suppose.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you danilo for your response but how i can handle on this on serever end because device developer send & receive message on openfire.So is it possible for me to delete messages on server.For this i have deleted messages on ofmessagearchive table from mysql but then also it is readable at device end.Then where openfire stored that messages you have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete an offline message and for that ofMessageArchive is not the relevant table.

Offline chat messages are stored in "*ofOffline*" table in Openfire. Whenever a user is identified as offline, Openfire stores incoming messages for that user in *ofOffline* table. And when that user comes online (sends initial presence), server picks all offline messages for that user and delivers it to him and immediately deletes them from *ofOffline*.

Now you can query that table against username and use *creationDate* column for date comparison which stores timestamp in milliseconds (13 digits) and prepends two zeros to it. (001234567890123)

Comment: Hi shoaib i want to delete chat messages of chatroom and it is only stored in ofmessagearchive table.ofoffline table only stored one to one chat messages.

Comment: For group chat, if conversation logging is enabled, then Openfire stores group conversations in "ofMucConversationLog", Can you confirm that this table is empty?

Comment: Yes i have checked there is some messages in ofmucconversation  log but the messages are old one,recent messages are not in this table.shoaib i want to confirm one thing if openfire get there messages from mysql table or from some where else.Because when we restart the openfire all messages are deleted.

Comment: Openfire does maintain data in memory (Maps, Lists) which is synced to database. In your case, i am sure that it's not related to "ofMessageArchive" because for getting messages from archive, you need to query the server (sending specific IQ packet). However, room history is replayed to user whenever he joins by MUC module. Kindly provide the actual presence stanza you are sending while joining a room.

Comment: presence stanza means code to create a room and joining a members in to room ?

Comment: If you are building an Android app using smack library or an iOS app using xmppframework, i need the actual packet which is sent for room joining. You should be able to get that if logging is working. For reference what i want to check: https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-managehistory

Comment: Actually i have created and joining a chat room in PHP using MUC plugin api of openfire in which i have send XML code to openfire.<chatRoom>
            
                <roomName>$roomName</roomName>
                  <naturalName>$naturalName</naturalName>
                <description>$description</description>
                <publicRoom>true</publicRoom>
                <persistent>true</persistent> 
<canOccupantsInvite>true</canOccupantsInvite>     
                <owners>
        $vars
    </owners>
    
            </chatRoom>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123412/discussion-between-shoaib-ahmad-gondal-and-varun-joshi).